# How to handle pagination if only javascript can be loaded in BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

It's been hours since I am stuck here.
The entire code has been uploaded below.
The url: "https://www.bostonpublicschools.org/Page/628" is of only 1 page. However, it has 5 pages within itself that can be loaded by clicking on the page-icon at the bottom. This loads a javascript file that cannot be opened on a new tab (trying to open results in page getting blocked). Also, it loads on the same page.

And along with that, I'm trying to fetch `EMail-IDs` by visiting individual websites. But there exist a catch which I'm unable to overcome. That is, some Email IDs exist within

tags and some in  tags and some more in different positions say index 3 or 2. Is there any way where I can fetch all of them? Yes,
`school.find('div', {'class': "ui-column-one-half region"}).find(class_="ui-article-description")`
this code can fetch them but it's really hard to filter as I mentioned before.

I've so far looked at more than 100 solutions and tried many of them and none of them worked for me. Also, I do believe that this can be solved by using `selenium` as it can interact with the UI.

Is there any way I can get the job done within BeautifulSoup?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

valid = False


def URL_Parser(url):
    # Desktop user-agent
    DESKTOP_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
    # Mobile user-agent
    MOBILE_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G930V Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36"

    headers = {"user-agent": MOBILE_USER_AGENT}
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return resp


def validate_mail(e_mail):
    return bool(re.search(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$", e_mail))


def main():
    global valid
    URL = "https://www.bostonpublicschools.org/Page/628"
    response = URL_Parser(URL)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(response.content, "html.parser")

        school_database = {"School Name": [],
                           "School Email ID": [],
                           "School Link": []
                           }

        links = []

        for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://www.bostonpublicschools.org/Page/")}):
            if link.get('aria-invalid'):
                links.append(link.get('href'))

        for link in links:
            school = bs(URL_Parser(link).content, 'html.parser')

            school_name = school.find('div', {'class': "ui-widget app flexpage"}).find(class_="ui-widget-header").select('h1')[0].text.strip()
            try:
                school_email = school.find('div', {'class': "ui-column-one-half region"}).find(class_="ui-article-description").select('p')[2].text.strip()
                valid = validate_mail(school_email)
                if not valid:
                    school_email = school.find('div', {'class': "ui-column-one-half region"}).find(class_="ui-article-description").select('p')[1].text.strip()
                    valid = validate_mail(school_email)
                    if not valid:
                        school_email = school.find('div', {'class': "ui-column-one-half region"}).find(class_="ui-article-description").select('p')[3].text.strip()
                        valid = validate_mail(school_email)

            except IndexError:
                print(">>> Email is not in expected place!")
            else:
                school_database["School Name"].append(school_name)
                school_database["School Email ID"].append(school_email)
                school_database["School Link"].append(link)

        print(school_database["School Link"])
        print(school_database["School Name"])
        print(school_database["School Email ID"])


if '__init__' == main():
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.bostonpublicschools.org/Page/628"

# get required parameters:
html_doc = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
url = re.search(r"window\.open\((.*)\);", html_doc).group(1)
ModuleInstanceID = re.search(r"ModuleInstanceID=(\d+)", url).group(1)
PageModuleInstanceID = re.search(r"PageModuleInstanceID=(\d+)", url).group(1)
DirectoryType = soup.select_one("[id$=displaytype]")["value"]
total_pages = int(soup.select(".ui-pagination-list li")[-1].text)

url = "https://www.bostonpublicschools.org/site/UserControls/Minibase/MinibaseListWrapper.aspx"

params = {
    "ModuleInstanceID": ModuleInstanceID,
    "PageModuleInstanceID": PageModuleInstanceID,
    "FilterFields": "",
    "DirectoryType": DirectoryType,
    "PageIndex": "",
}

# iterate over the pages and print sample info:
for params["PageIndex"] in range(1, total_pages + 1):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(url, params=params).content, "html.parser"
    )

    for a in soup.select(".sw-flex-item-group a"):
        print(a.text)
```

Prints:

```
...

UP Academy Holland
Warren/Prescott K-8
West Zone Early Learning Center
Winship, F. Lyman Elementary
Winthrop, John Elementary
Young Achievers Science & Math K-8
```

Comment: Mind telling the way you found the URL to the list wrapper?  I got all the links to their specific school links following this code. Running this through a loop got me the details. However, the same indexing problem do exist still. Some of them exist inside the div and some of them in the p tags and etc. I'll try to get through the same method again.. Thank you though.

Comment: @SIM Can you please add that as a separate answer? I'll upvote it :)

Comment: Sorry Andrej, but if I choose that route, it will unquestionably be dishonest. You have already answered it in the right way. I just tried to show OP how he can do the rest as he seems to be curious.

Comment: This answer actually solved the problem with pagination. However, I'm still waiting for @AndrejKesely to reply about this part of the code: url = "https://www.bostonpublicschools.org/site/UserControls/Minibase/MinibaseListWrapper.aspx". And many to thanks to SIM(I couldn't add another user) for guiding me with email address. I've to try that out now. Marking as solved.

Comment: @SIM, `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`. This is what I'm getting upon trying the code unfortunately.

Comment: Yea, I just test ran your script, it worked flawlessly. I tried to split your code by passing the soup directly as I had already got it, I think that's where I've messed up.

Comment: @SIM, around 32 emails have found to be missing and on 120th loop, it gives AttributeError. It was giving me the for long time, until I figured out your script had the same issue

Comment: This is the page `https://www.bostonpublicschools.org/Page/869` which causes the issue. Okay, I'm done answering your questions. Try debugging them yourself if you further encounter any issue.